# ImportError: No module named pyqt_ui.qt_translator

Tags: python, packaging, py2app

I'm attempting to package a python application ([Mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org)) using py2app (I didn't write the software; I am only attempting to package it).

I have built the application with py2app:
`sudo python setup.py py2app`

and copied the qt_menu.nib directory into the Resources directory.

When I then attempt to launch the application:
`./dist/Mnemosyne.app/Contents/MacOS/Mnemosyne`

I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named pyqt_ui.qt_translator

I haven't been able to figure out what to add to the "includes" to ensure qt_translator is included.

I read the [list of PyQT modules](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/modules.html) but I couldn't find which module I need to include to get qt_translator.  I learned that there is a `QTranslator` class in the QtCore module, but including `PyQt4.QtCore` doesn't help, nor does `PyQt4*`.

The line in the code that seems to be causing this is:

```
mnemosyne.components.insert(0,
                            ("mnemosyne.pyqt_ui.qt_translator",
                             "QtTranslator"))
```

Comment: You need more information. Explain what your script imports. Tell us what classes you have already downloaded and installed/implemented.

Comment: @CGeniusGo I added as much information as I could.  Please let me know if this still isn't enough.

Comment: Have you installed the [pyqt modules](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are missing is part of the package that you download when you download the Mnemosyne [tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mnemosyne-proj/files/mnemosyne/mnemosyne-2.0/Mnemosyne-2.0.tar.gz/download) it is in the folder mnemosyne/pyqt_ui file name qt_translator.py you need to extract the entire tarball and cd into it in terminal then use py2app.

Comment: I added the following module to includes to get it working: `mnemosyne.pyqt_ui.*`